# Multiple projects for Application Services in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: configuration, aspnetboilerplate

I have an application with two projects that contain `IApplicationService` classes, but the framework only resolves client proxies (in JavaScript: `abp.services.app.xxxx`) by default for **Application** project that comes with base template.

```
myProject.Application => default ASP.NET Boilerplate
```

```
myProject.ExtraServices => my own (not generating client proxies)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core

Create controllers for your `ExtraServices` project in [MyProjectWebCoreModule](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/AbpProjectNameWebCoreModule.cs#L49-L52):

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore()
    .CreateControllersForAppServices(
        typeof(ExtraServicesModule).GetAssembly()
    );
```

## ASP.NET MVC 5

Create controllers for your `ExtraServices` project in [MyProjectWebApiModule](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/c0d7f0433d573a8207b27f817e1d188c215f1e50/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebApi/Api/AbpProjectNameWebApiModule.cs#L17-L19):

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .ForAll<IApplicationService>(typeof(ExtraServicesModule).Assembly, "app")
    .Build();
```