# New Application(Service) new Core, no Swagger?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

To a working ABPboilerplate I added an additional pair of .Application and .Core modules based on what I see in the working code. Build/run is fine, but when I run the Web.Host /swagger, I do not see my new Dto APIs in the swagger list. What else do I need? Or, what does swagger parse and when/where is the swagger-parser kicked off? I do not see a configuration other than the general swagger configuration in the Startup.cs. Thanks!

EDIT: We are using the ASP.NET-Core MVC/JQuery permeation of the boilerplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AspNet Boilerplate, Multiple Application Services Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300026/aspnet-boilerplate-multiple-application-services-projects)

Comment: Thanks, yes, that did the trick.

Comment: Oh, you can't close your own question as a duplicate [if you edit your question after the Close Vote was cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356930/8601760). You should still be able to [flag it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364823/8601760), which is more appropriate.